# Do progress tokens carry forward in the Lord of the Rings LCG?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

If you've successfully quested during the quest phase and come out +7, but you only need 3 more quest points to finish the current stage, do you put your extra 4 progress tokens on the quest card for the next stage or can you only make progress through one stage per round?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you place all progress tokens at once, so you can't get progress on the next stage of the quest by overcompleting the first one.